# How to iterate an Array inside an iterating set of JSON outputs in Angular?

Tags: angular, loops, iteration, output

I have a database table which save data about hotels. A hotel can have multiple contact numbers and implemented using a composite table for contact numbers.
I want to display all the information of existing hotels. My output displays everything else other than the contact numbers. Please tell me a way to iterate and show the contact numbers of each hotel.

Here's the data coming to front end

```
address1: "No 400,"
address2: "Beach Road,"
city: "Colombo"
contacts: Array(2)
0: {contactNo: "0712244587"}
1: {contactNo: "0775469823"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
email: "kingsbury@gmail.com"
hid: 1
hotelName: "Kingsbury"
state: "Western"
zipCode: "10000"
```

.html code

```
<div
            class="card"
            style="height: 750px;"
            *ngFor="let hotel of availableHotels"
          >
            <div class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body">
                <img
                  style="width: 15cm; height: auto;"
                  src="../../assets/images/car2.jpg"
                  class="card-img"
                  id="img"
                  alt="..."
                />
                <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;">Hotel : {{ hotel.hotelName }}</h2>
                <h4 >{{ hotel.city }}</h4>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">Address : {{hotel.address1}}</p>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">Contact : </p>
             <div *ngFor="let contact of {{hotel.contact}};let i=index">
                  <p>{{contact.contactNo}}</p>
                </div>
           
                <p class="font-weight-bold">Email : {{hotel.email}}</p>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

.ts code

```
export class TestcComponent implements OnInit {

  availableHotels: Array<any>;
  hotel: ReplaySubject<String> = new ReplaySubject();
  

  constructor(
    private contractService: ContractService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.contractService.findAllHotels().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.availableHotels = data;
      data.forEach((item) => {
        this.hotel.next(item);
        
        });
 

});
}
}
```

How output is shown :

```
Hotel : Shangri-La
Colombo 10
Address : No 400,

Contact :

Email : shangrila@gmail.com
```

I'm new to angular and still trying to get familiar with things. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```html
<div *ngFor="let contact of {{hotel.contact}};let i=index">
  <p>{{contact.contactNo}}</p>
</div>
```

to

```html
<div *ngFor="let contact of hotel?.contact; let i=index;">
  <p>{{contact?.contactNo}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need interpolation in the `*ngFor` definition. You could access the property directly. The [micro-syntax](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) `*ngFor` is expanded to property binding `[ngForOf]="hotel.contacts"` so it's already evaluated as an expression.

Try the following

```html
<div *ngFor="let contact of hotel?.contacts; let i=index">
  <p>{{ contact.contactNo }}</p>
</div>
```

<sup>I've used `hotel.contacts` because I don't see `hotel.contact` in the back-end data you've shown.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax, please follow the below code -

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of hotel?.contact;let i=index">
  <p>{{contact?.contactNo}}</p>
</div>
```

> **Reason**

You can't use interpolation syntax `{{}}` with inbuilt directives like `*ngFor`, because the equation on left side is evaluated in these cases.